# To Show that $\exp(tX)\exp(tY)= \exp(t(X+Y)) + (1/2)t^2[X, Y] +o(t^3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups

> **Problem 20-9** in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd Ed.) asks to prove that for a Lie group $G$, and for $X, Y\in \text{Lie}(G)=\mathfrak g$, there is $\epsilon>0$ and a smooth map $Z:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to \mathfrak g$ such that
>   $$(\exp tX)(\exp tY) = \exp\left(t(X+Y) + \frac{1}{2}t^2[X, Y] + t^3 Z(t)\right)$$

What we want to show is that the first and second term in the Taylor expansion of $\exp^{-1}\left((\exp tX)(\exp tY)\right)$ are $t(X+Y)$ and $\frac{1}{2}t^2[X, Y]$ respectively.

Calculating the first term is easy since we just need to differentiate $\exp^{-1}((\exp tX)(\exp tY))$ with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ once, and this gives the desired result.

But for the second term we need to take the second derivative at which I am stuck.

Comment: You could always use the power series expansion.

Comment: You can use as reference Brian Hall's notes "An Elementary Introduction to Groups and Representations", chapter 4.1 (https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005032)

Answer (score 2):

At the second order for the left hand side

$$\begin{split}e^{tX}e^{tY}&=(1+tX+\frac{t^2}{2} X^2)(1+tY+\frac{t^2}{2}Y^2)\\
&=1+t(X+Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}(2XY+X^2+Y^2)\end{split}$$

At the second order, we rewrite the right hand side as

$$\begin{split}e^{t(X+Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}f(X,Y)}&=1+t(X+Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}f(X,Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}(X+Y)^2\\
&=1+t(X+Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}f(X,Y)+\frac{t^2}{2}(X^2+XY+YX+Y^2)\end{split}$$

Equating both sides, you find

$$2XY+X^2+Y^2=f(X,Y)+X^2+XY+YX+Y^2$$

So you arrive to

$$f(X,Y)=XY-YX=[X,Y]$$

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by $X^2$. Here $X$ is a left-invariant vector field on the Lie group.

Comment: The proof is only correct when $X,Y$ are matrix.